# Make a div into a link

Tags: css, html, xhtml, anchor

I have a `<div>` block with some fancy visual content that I don't want to change. I want to make it a clickable link.

I'm looking for something like `<a href="…"><div> … </div></a>`, but that is valid XHTML 1.1.

Comment: one good reason would be a background image in the div

Comment: I have a good working example based on the most voted answer. Check the fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/mrivasa/TK69d/)

Comment: In HTML5 it is perfectly valid to have a `div` under an `a`.

Answer (score 784):

Came here in the hope of finding a better solution that mine, but I don't like any of the ones on offer here. I think some of you have misunderstood the question. The OP wants to make a div full of content behave like a link. One example of this would be facebook ads - if you look, they're actually proper markup.

For me the no-nos are: javascript (shouldn't be needed just for a link, and very bad SEO/accessibility); invalid HTML.

In essence it's this:

- Build your panel using normal CSS techniques and valid HTML.
- Somewhere in there put a link that you want to be the default link if the user clicks on the panel (you can have other links too).
- Inside that link, put an empty span tag (`<span></span>`, not `<span />` - thanks @Campey)
- give the panel position:relative
- apply the following CSS to the empty span:

  ```
  { 
    position:absolute; 
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    top:0;
    left: 0;

    z-index: 1;

    /* fixes overlap error in IE7/8, 
       make sure you have an empty gif */
    background-image: url('empty.gif');
  }
  ```

  It will now cover the panel, and as it's inside an `<A>` tag, it's a clickable link
- give any other links inside the panel position:relative and a suitable z-index (>1) to bring them in front of the default span link

Comment: Great solution, used it for a 'lightbox' using pure CSS3 that allows users to click the darkened area and transition back to the previous fragment.

Comment: Thanks works well. If things break horribly (like they did for me) in IE8, make sure you have an opening and closing span tag (<span...></span>), instead of an empty span (<span... />).

Comment: The code doesn't work entirely in IE7/8, other elements that are selectable take precedence over the `<a><span></span></a>` element. I.e. images and texts inside the container won't link even if the z-index is set.

Comment: In order to [get it to work for old IE](http://www.ngenworks.com/blog/ie_z_index_and_making_a_div_a_link/) you need to set the span's `background-image` to an empty gif.

Comment: A fiddle for people who are silly like me and misread something so had to play around with it a bit: http://jsfiddle.net/hf75B/1/

Comment: I came by with a similar solution in a user style that I'm writing. Since I cannot change the markup I wanted a valid, CSS-only, solution. I used the `:after` pseudo-element with blank content (`content: "";`). I did not check this one thoroughly for cross-browser compatibility as I only need this to work in Firefox. The rest is just about the same as suggested in your solution.

Comment: Personally, I use <span>&nbsp;</span> as a rule of thumb.

Comment: Have you tried this in IE9?  I like this method, and I am using it, but I just tested it (including the fiddle from @AlexMA) in IE9, and what I'm seeing is that you can click anywhere in the div EXCEPT on the text.  When you hover over the text, the cursor changes to a standard text cursor and it does nothing when you click on the text.   As users are prone to click on text elements (and when the text elements fill up most of the div), it makes this solution unusable in IE9.  Has anyone else experienced this or have a solution?

Comment: Adding just the background-image line to my <div> worked perfectly to make the area clickable in IE.   This was for existing code that I couldn't refactor on a short schedule.

Comment: If there are nested DIVs, how will it know which one to make clickable?

Comment: It will be the innermost div with position: relative

Comment: Problem I'm running into is making other links within the div clickable.

Comment: @jacobsimeon read the last point in the post.  To make links within the div clickable, make their position relative and z-index greater than 1

Comment: You don't really need to add an empty span inside the link. You can add the actual name of the link for SEO, then hide it using `text-indent: -9999px; overflow: hidden;`

Comment: I was stuck on this for a while, and found out that my wrapping div had to have `{ position: relative }`.

Comment: An issue with this solution is that it blocks any element behind the link overlay to receive a hover effect. If you have :hover style on any element inside, that style will never trigger.

Comment: Pretty sure you can fix that using z-index, the same way you would other links inside the box

Comment: Very interesting solution. I was nearly there apart from the span tag in the a tag. Thanks for a really good solution

Comment: Does anybody know how to have :hover css work with this solution? Perhaps referring the answer put in the fiddle?

Comment: @nktokyo did you ever find an answer to your question -- getting :hover to work with this solution?

Comment: I was able to make this work without putting `position: relative` on the panel `<div>`. What am I doing right?

Comment: Great answer. Just wondering why i need the nested span element. Why cant i apply the css on the <a> element itself.

Comment: @JoeStarbright because you want the text inside that <a> to be somewhere in the body of your div.

Comment: For those who still struggle with showing the pointer, this addition worked for me `pointer-events: auto`

Comment: Not being able to edit the div this worked: By adding padding and equal amounts of negative margin you can 'expand' the area that is clickable on the <a> tag. For example: if an <a> tag is in a list of <div> elements and each <a> is has an icon before it and a <span> after it. To cause the icon and the span at either side of the <a> element to be clickable i added this css: padding-left: 25px; margin-left: -25px; padding-right: 30px; margin-right: -30px;

Answer (score 285):

You can't make the `div` a link itself, but you can make an `<a>` tag act as a `block`, the same behaviour a `<div>` has.

```
a {
    display: block;
}
```

You can then set the width and height on it.

Comment: However, this doesn't make a 'div' into a link.  It makes a link into a block element.  It's a bit different.

Comment: You could make a span a block element too, but there is a reason for different HTML elements.

Comment: This is solution of your problem. Because you can modify div can be clicked like hyperlink, but you can't set cursor(=hand) for display in all browser(only IE support it!).

Comment: Using an 'a' tag for a block is like using tables for layout IMHO.

Comment: jjnguy: How? I dislike having lots of content in a link, but this could just as well be part of a navigation menu or something like that. An anchor element (<a>) doesn't necessarily have to be plain text, does it? In which way is it _wrong_ to make it into a block? It's semantically correct and it can be used to display it as you want.

Comment: This is a perfectly valid solution to a vague question. You actually COULD simply wrap an anchor element around a div, but that would be semantically incorrect. (Block element within inline element).

Comment: jjnguy: This is pretty common practice.  I'm not saying replace divs with links, but by the sounds of the question he just wanted a block he could click like a button or something.

Comment: the solution is valid, no doubt, the the OP did not request this functionality....

Comment: This worked in my situation and was the best solution. I made it an inline-block and added width: 100% to stretch it across the entire enclosing div. This solved a dropdown menu problem where if the link was forced to wrap an inadvertently click simply closed the menu.

Comment: @Traingamer Maybe to *a* vague question, but not this one. This question specifically asks for how to make a *div* into a link. It is abundantly obvious that answers which don't even use `div`s cannot be a valid answer to this question.

Comment: @Kröw it is incredibly vague. They didn't show any code, didn't explain why they used a div, or why they'd want to keep it a div. Nor was any reason given for wanting to wrap the div other than to make it behave like a link. They also didn't specify if they wanted to avoid javascript or not, etc. So this is very open ended which is why there are so many potential solutions provided.

Comment: @Soviut That is not true at all. I reiterate that this question specifically asks for how to make a *div* into a link. The question title is short and sweet: `Make a div into a link`. Your curiosity as to why a div was used would be well-resolved through a comment, but providing an answer that escapes the question is something to have to scroll through for users who want an answer to exactly what the question is. If you have useful information that answers a different (albeit similar) question, it is recommended to open a new question and self-answer it, (and perhaps, reference this question).

Comment: @Kröw Please stop cluttering up the comments with this. The question is vague and open to interpretation, otherwise there would be a single answer. For example, there's no reason given for breaking HTML semantics. Since they weren't clear about "why", offering solutions that are semantically valid is perfectly reasonable.

Comment: @Soviut There is no purpose in you asking me to simply stop "cluttering the comments;" I would ask you the same thing because I think what you're pointing out is not correct (or if I think it is not relevant). Anyway, the question is vague and open to interpretation, but that does not mean I can talk about my favorite fútbol team in an answer. The question may be vague but it's still very clear what isn't an answer. Semantic validity doesn't make what you posted an answer. Your post is still a semantically valid answer to a *different* question.

Comment: @Soviut Your "answer" is useful, but I strongly suggest you take the more appropriate approach of writing a new question and self-answering it when you have useful information that does not answer the existing question again in the future. (I already suggested linking the original question too. This is useful advice.) Adding a post that does not answer the question exactly does clutter up the page with answers that do not help many others with the same question.

Comment: The problem with this solution is: when you put an `img` into an `a` rendered as `block`, the outer `a` and the inner `img` do not have the same height.

Comment: @ceving that's solved by giving the `img` a `display: block` removing whitespace characters in your HTML. However, if they were using an image, they technically don't need to do anything to the `a` since the `img` will give it block-like behaviour (despite both being inline).

Answer (score 88):

This is an ancient question, but I thought I'd answer it since everyone here has some crazy solutions. It's actually very very simple...

An anchor tag works like this -

```
<a href="whatever you want"> EVERYTHING IN HERE TURNS INTO A LINK </a>
```

Sooo...

```
<a href="whatever you want"> <div id="thediv" /> </a>
```

Although I'm not sure if this is valid. If that's the reasoning behind spoken solutions, then I apologise...

Comment: It's valid HTML as long as the `<div>` doesn't contain any interactive content (other `<a>` elements, `<button>` elements, etc.).

Comment: Your example is not valid HTML - block element contained in an inline element - *unless* you're using HTML5, which has made an exception for links.

Comment: This is a *bad* example, because what the `a` tag does is takes all the text in a `div` and underlines it... this can be mitigated with styling, but the top answer is better.

Comment: `a #thediv{font-weight:normal;text-decoration:none;}` is all you need style-wise.

Comment: no. just simple converting div into inline would not do the job. It is bad markup, and... just read this:

http://skypoetsworld.blogspot.in/2008/10/dont-ever-put-block-inside-inline.html

Comment: Tried this and it worked, however it broke the element's positioning.  Yes doctype is HTML5 in Chrome (some 2014 version)..

Comment: not valid xhtml - you shouldn't put block elements inside inline elements, even if you change the 'display' property with css

Comment: Yeah I saw a CodeAcademy course has done it this way too. https://www.codecademy.com/en/courses/web-beginner-en-f8mcL/2/2?curriculum_id=50579fb998b470000202dc8b

Comment: It is a valid answer for HTML 5, but not for HTML 4-

Comment: made all the `<p>` tags underneath turn blue. Even when setting  `a text-decoration: none`

Answer (score 77):

Requires a little javascript.
But, your `div` would be clickable.

```
<div onclick="location.href='http://www.example.com';" style="cursor:pointer;"></div>
```

Comment: Results in bad semantics on the page though, so I'd avoid this one even though it is technically possible.

Comment: Functional, but not really in the spirit of the question which is for an XHTML solution.

Comment: I thought about using this solution, but it's kind of ugly. I like the solutions involving display: block better.

Comment: This looks like a link, but isn't a real link.  It has severe usability and accesibility issues, and is a really nasty solution.

Comment: Best solution. We just need to run script and send "this" to it.

Comment: If your manager tells you to do it asap tell him its bad semantics lol

Comment: If it's not possible to use a anchor as a block then this is the best substitute. This way will also let you add a link without making any changes to the CSS code.

Comment: If they don't have js enabled you lost functionality.  As well as being bad for SEO.

Comment: This doesn't give you a mouse cursor.

Comment: I'm doing a single page web app. So I don't have to worry about SEO and this is the easiest solution for me.

Comment: @SmallChess it does for me. Best answer that completely worked for me.

Answer (score 53):

This option doesn’t require an empty.gif as in the most upvoted answer:

HTML:

```
 <div class="feature">
       <a href="http://www.example.com"></a>
 </div>
```

CSS:

```
 div.feature {
        position: relative;
    }

    div.feature a {
        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        text-decoration: none; /* No underlines on the link */
        z-index: 10; /* Places the link above everything else in the div */
        background-color: #FFF; /* Fix to make div clickable in IE */
        opacity: 0; /* Fix to make div clickable in IE */
        filter: alpha(opacity=1); /* Fix to make div clickable in IE */
    }
```

As proposed at http://www.digitalskydesign.com/how-to-make-an-entire-div-a-link-using-css/

Comment: Thanks! Chris Jumonville's solution is working great on both Andriod and iPhone. Example: http://gastateparks.org/specials

Comment: Shouldn't it be `div.feature > a` just in case the "everything else" part also contains a link hidden deep within?

Comment: this should be the choosen answer, works with bootstrap too

Comment: This works beautifully, very smooth, works with screen readers nicely too, HTML5 adhering, works even if you do transforms on the parent object, and inherently makes the cursor into a pointer (as you expect for a clickable object)

Answer (score 25):

The cleanest way would be to use jQuery with the data-tags introduced in HTML. With this solution you can create a link on every tag you want. First define the tag (e.g. div) with a data-link tag:

```html
<div data-link="http://www.google.at/">Some content in the div which is arbitrary</div>
```

Now you can style the div however you want. And you have to create also the style for the "link"-alike behavior:

```css
[data-link] {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

And at last put this jQuery call to the page:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("[data-link]").click(function() {
    window.location.href = $(this).attr("data-link");
    return false;
  });
});
```

With this code jQuery applys a click listener to every tag on the page which has a "data-link" attribute and redirects to the URL which is in the data-link attribute.

Comment: To get info about data-attributes see: http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/

Answer (score 24):

This is a "valid" solution to achieving what you want.

```
<style type="text/css">
.myspan {
    display: block;
}
</style>
<a href="#"><span class="myspan">text</span></a>
```

But most-likely what you really want is to have an `<a>` tag displayed as a block level element.

I would not advise using JavaScript to simulate a hyperlink as that defeats the purpose of markup validation, which is ultimately to promote accessibility (publishing well-formed documents following proper semantic rules minimizes the possibility the same document will be interpreted differently by different browsers).

It would be preferable to publish a web page that does not validate, but *renders and functions properly on all browsers*, including ones with JavaScript disabled. Furthermore, using `onclick` does not provide the semantic information for a screen reader to determine that the div is functioning as a link.

Answer (score 20):

Not sure if this is valid but it worked for me.

The code :

```html
<div style='position:relative;background-color:#000000;width:600px;height:30px;border:solid;'>
  <p style='display:inline;color:#ffffff;float:left;'> Whatever </p>     
  <a style='position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px;width:100%;height:100%;display:inline;' href ='#'></a>
</div>
```

Comment: I have to say that this approach is as clean as a css class on your stylesheet.
as far as i am concerned, this is the correct and most easy solution.

Comment: This is the best one

Answer (score 10):

To make thepeer's answer work in IE 7 and forward, it needs a few tweaks.

1. IE will not honour z-index if the element is has no background-color, so the link will not overlap parts of the containig div that has content, only the blank parts. To fix this a background is added with opacity 0.
2. For some reason IE7 and various compatibility modes completely fail when using the span in a link approach. However if the link itself is given the style it works just fine.

```css
.blockLink  
{  
    position:absolute;  
    top:0;  
    left: 0;  
    width:100%;  
    height:100%;  
    z-index: 1;  
    background-color:#ffffff;   
    -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";  
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);  
    opacity:0;  
}
```

```html
<div style="position:relative">  
    <some content>  
    <a href="somepage" class="blockLink" />  
<div>
```

Answer (score 9):

you could also try by wrapping an anchor, then turning its height and width to be the same with its parent. This works for me perfectly.

```
<div id="css_ID">
    <a href="http://www.your_link.com" style="display:block; height:100%; width:100%;"></a>
</div>
```

Comment: You might also want to make sure the parent div has zero padding and that the <a> tag has zero margin.

Answer (score 8):

An option that hasn't been mentioned is using flex. By applying `flex: 1` to the `a` tag, it expands to fit the container.

```css
div {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid;
}

a {
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <a href="http://google.co.uk">Link</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6):

This worked for me:

HTML:

```
<div>

  WHATEVER YOU WANT

  <a href="YOUR LINK HERE">
    <span class="span-link"></span>
  </a>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
.span-link {
  position:absolute;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  top:0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 9999;
}
```

This adds an invisible element (the span), which covers your entire div, and is *above* your whole div on the z-index, so when someone clicks on that div, the click is essentially intercepted by your invisible "span" layer, which is linked.

Note: If you're already using z-indexes for other elements, just make sure the value of this z-index is higher than anything you want it to rest "on top" of.

Comment: Worked for me. Just don't forget to relatively position the parent element.

Answer (score 5):

why not? `use <a href="bla"> <div></div> </a>` works fine in HTML5

Comment: It won't pass HTML validation. Line item cannot store block items.

Comment: I mean, that `<div><span></span></div>` is valid and `<span><div></div></span>` is not.  You shouldn't put `display: inline;` type of items into `display: block;` items. The `<a>` tag is inline box.

Comment: Yeah, it can work, because You can do it in multiple ways (better or worse). This particular solution is not good cause the older HTML validation :).

Comment: Does it matter that "older HTML validation" does not pass this? It is allowed now, html5 and for a reason so why not use it? I think this solution is fine (it does often require the removal of underline to the div content but still).

Comment: @Todilo Because while `<a><div></div></a>` is valid and works, `<a><div><a></a></div></a>` is not valid and doesn't work.

Answer (score 4):

This post is Old I know but I just had to fix the same issue because simply writing  a normal link tag with the display set to block does not make the whole div clickable in IE. so to fix this issue far simpler than having to use JQuery.

Firstly let us understand why this happens: IE wont make an empty div clickable it only make the text/image within that div/a tag clickable.

Solution: Fill the div with a bakground image and hide it from the viewer.

How?
You ask good questions, now listen up.
add this backround style to the a tag

```
> "background:url('some_small_image_path')
> -2000px -2000px no-repeat;"
```

And there you have it the whole div is now clickable. This was the best way for me cause Im using it for my Photo Gallery to let the user clik on one half of the image to move left/right and then place a small image as well just for visual effects. so for me I used the left and right images as background images anyway!

Comment: Thanks! I needed to simulate an imagemap with empty anchors over an image and IE would only let you click if there was content. This fixed it.

Answer (score 4):

This example worked for me:

```
<div style="position: relative; width:191px; height:83px;">
    <a href="link.php" style="display:block; width:100%; height:100%;"></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Just have the link in the block and enhance it with jquery. It degrades 100% gracefully for anyone without javascript. Doing this with html isn't really the best solution imho.
For example:

```
<div id="div_link">
<h2><a href="mylink.htm">The Link and Headline</a></h2>
<p>Some more stuff and maybe another <a href="mylink.htm">link</a>.</p>
</div>
```

Then use jquery to make the block clickable (via [web designer wall](http://www.webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/jquery-tutorials-for-designers/)):

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#div_link").click(function(){
      window.location=$(this).find("a").attr("href"); return false;
    });

});
```

Then all you have to do is add cursor styles to the div

```
    #div_link:hover {cursor: pointer;}
```

For bonus points only apply these styles if javascript is enabled by adding a 'js_enabled' class to the div, or the body, or whatever.

Comment: i want to use this but i have 2 links in the div... how can i modify it to be able click on both links?  (it currently takes me to "mylink.html" if i click the second link as well..)

Answer (score 3):

This is the best way to do it as used on the BBC website and the Guardian:

I found the technique here:
http://codepen.io/IschaGast/pen/Qjxpxo

heres the html

```
<div class="highlight block-link">
      <h2>I am an example header</h2>
      <p><a href="pageone" class="block-link__overlay-link">This entire box</a> links somewhere, thanks to faux block links. I am some example text with a <a href="pagetwo">custom link</a> that sits within the block</p>

</div>
```

heres the CSS

```
/**
 * Block Link
 *
 * A Faux block-level link. Used for when you need a block-level link with
 * clickable areas within it as directly nesting a tags breaks things.
 */


.block-link {
    position: relative;
}

.block-link a {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

.block-link .block-link__overlay-link {
    position: static;
    &:before {
      bottom: 0;
      content: "";
      left: 0;
      overflow: hidden;
      position: absolute;
      right: 0;
      top: 0;
      white-space: nowrap;
      z-index: 0;
    }
    &:hover,
    &:focus {
      &:before {
        background: rgba(255,255,0, .2);
      }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Actually you need to include the JavaScript code at the moment,
check [this tutorial](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/make-entire-div-clickable/) to do so.

but there is a tricky way to achieve this using a CSS code
you must nest an anchor tag inside your div tag and you must apply this property to it,

```
display:block;
```

when you've done that,it will make the whole width area clickable (but within the height of the anchor tag),if you want to cover the whole div area you must set the height of the anchor tag exactly to the height of the div tag,for example:

```
height:60px;
```

this is gonna make the whole area clickable,then you can apply `text-indent:-9999px` to anchor tag to achieve the goal.

this is really tricky and simple and it's just created using CSS code.

here is an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/hbirjand/RG8wW/): http://jsfiddle.net/hbirjand/RG8wW/

Answer (score 2):

```
<a href="…" style="cursor: pointer;"><div> … </div></a>
```

Answer (score 1):

This work for me:

```
<div onclick="location.href='page.html';"  style="cursor:pointer;">...</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the simplest way.

Say, this is the `div` block I want to make clickable:

```
<div class="inner_headL"></div>
```

So put a `href` as follows:

```
<a href="#">
 <div class="inner_headL"></div>
</a>
```

Just consider the `div` block as a normal html element and enable the usual a `href` tag. 

It works on FF at least.

Answer (score 1):

You can give a link to your div by following method:

```
<div class="boxdiv" onClick="window.location.href='https://www.google.co.in/'">google</div>
<style type="text/css">
.boxdiv {
    cursor:pointer;
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    background-color:#FF0000;
    color:#fff;
    text-align:center;
    font:13px/17px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make surround the element with a href tags or you can use jquery and use

```
$('').click(function(e){
e.preventDefault();
//DO SOMETHING
});
```

Answer (score 0):

While I don't recommend doing this under any circumstance, here is some code that makes a DIV into a link (note: this example uses jQuery and certain markup is removed for simplicity):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("div[href]").click(function () {
        window.location = $(this).attr("href");
    });
});

</script>
<div href="http://www.google.com">
     My Div Link
</div>
```

Comment: Again, this is a functional solution, but not really in the spirit of the original question which was for an XHTML solution. While not a huge deal, your answer *does* start to add noise to the question.

Answer (score 0):

I pulled in  a variable because some values in my link will change depending on what record the user is coming from. 
This worked for testing :

```
   <div onclick="location.href='page.html';"  style="cursor:pointer;">...</div>
```

and this works too :

```
   <div onclick="location.href='<%=Webpage%>';"  style="cursor:pointer;">...</div>
```

Comment: code doesn't show for some reason I used the onclick with a jsp variable inside to create a dynamic link

Answer (score 0):

Enclosing your `div` inside an anchor tag `<a href></a>` works like charm:

```
    <a href="">
      <div>anything goes here will turn into a link</div>
    </a>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can use bootstrap, one simple solution is to use bootstrap `.stretched-link`.

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/utilities/stretched-link/

Sample Code

```
<div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
  <img src="..." class="card-img-top" alt="...">
  <div class="card-body">
    <h5 class="card-title">Card with stretched link</h5>
    <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary stretched-link">Go somewhere</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

[Soviut's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/796096/402322) was not sufficient for me. I had to use

```css
a { display: inline-flex; }
```

to remove baseline artifacts, when using just a `img` in the `a`.

Answer (score 0):

Pure HTML & CSS case. No JS.

In case if you want to have other link elements inside of that fully clickable div.

Main idea is to stretch main clickable link, place it under the content, and disable clicks for content with [pointer-events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events). For clickable elements inside of this element, set `pointer-events: all;` for each one.

Live demo:

```html
<div style="
            width: 300px; height: 300px;
            position: relative;
            border: 1px red solid;
            pointer-events: none;
            z-index: 0;
            ">
  <h1>No wrapper</h1>
  <p>This is fully clickable div, click handled by anchor tag. It contains no wrapper</p>
  <button>Learn more</button>

  <p>See this link ➡️ <a style="pointer-events: all;" title="Why I see this ad?" href="http://example.com/">?</a></p>

  <a style="
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;left: 0;right: 0; bottom: 0;
            text-indent: -9999px;overflow: hidden;
            pointer-events: all;
            z-index: -1;
            " title="GO TO YANDEX" href="https://ya.ru">CLICK</a>
</div>
```

Codepen: https://codepen.io/ColCh/pen/OJaPpJQ

Answer (score 0):

```
 <div role="button"></div>
```

Comment: Avoid code only answer and provide an explanation.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<div class="relative">
  <a href="http://example.com" class="absolute top-0 left-0 right-0 bottom-0 bg-opacity-0 z-1 pointer-events-none">
    <span></span>
  </a>
  <div class="relative z-2">
    <button>Click me</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Additional to the top answer, for those who want the underlying elements to be clickable, you can do this by simply adding `position: relative` and `z-index: 2`.

Answer (score -2):

My smarty pants answer:

"Evasive answer to: "How to make block level element a hyperlink and validate in XHTML 1.1"

Just use HTML5 DOCTYPE DTD."

Didn't actually hold true for ie7

`onclick="location.href='page.html';"`

Works IE7-9, Chrome, Safari, Firefox,

Comment: he was looking for "I am looking for an XHTML 1.1 valid way"

Answer (score -4):

if just everything could be this simple...

```
#logo {background:url(../global_images/csg-4b15a4b83d966.png) no-repeat top left;background-position:0 -825px;float:left;height:48px;position:relative;width:112px}

#logo a {padding-top:48px; display:block;}



<div id="logo"><a href="../../index.html"></a></div>
```

just think a little outside the box ;-)