# Linking Text Logo and span

Tags: ruby-on-rails

how do i  link my Logo which is made out of Text and CSS to my root_path and the  inside of it?

This is how it would look without Rails:

```
<h1><a href=#>Main Title<span>subtitle</span></a></h1>
```

I am using no images and just plain CSS text for the Logo.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean link to root page:

`<h1><%= link_to 'Main Title<span>subtitle</span>'.html_safe, '/' %></h1>`

If you want other locations and have some resources set up, you could use paths:

`<h1><%= link_to 'Main Title<span>subtitle</span>'.html_safe, example_path %></h1>`

---

If you happen to need even more HTML markup in the link, then check this question out:

- **[How do I wrap link_to around some html ruby code?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1086360/308759)**

Comment: Normally strings are HTML escaped. If you want to stuff some arbitrary HTML tags in there as in this case, you have to designate the string as *safe*, so that it's printed out explicitly. This was introduced some time ago as a way to help circumvent XSS attacks. More on here: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2009/10/12/what-s-new-in-edge-rails

Comment: hmm i am using a mixture of html and ruby code so its very helpful to point out the .HTML_SAFE tag, ill do some more research on this. Thank you!