# Use link_to helper wrap some HTML

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I want to use link_to wrap some HTML,but I meet some problem.

```
<%= link_to 'index', { :controller => "user" , :action => "resume" }, :class => is_active?("index") do %>
  <li class="usidebar-index">index</li>
<% end %> 

<a href="index" controller="user" action="resume">
  <li class="usidebar-index">index</li>
</a>
```

I also have tried:

```
<%= link_to 'index',{ :controller => "user", :action => "resume" },  :class => is_active?("index") do %>
  <li class="usidebar-index">index</li>
<% end %>

<a href="index" action="resume" controller="user">
  <li class="usidebar-index">indx</li>
</a>
```

What I want is:

```
<a href="index" class="some-style">
  <li class="usidebar-index">index</li>
</a>
```

Could you help me?Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I wrap link\_to around some html ruby code?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1086360/how-do-i-wrap-link-to-around-some-html-ruby-code)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

per the [rails documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to):

```
<%= link_to({:controller => "user" , :action => "resume" }, :class => is_active?("index")) do %>

  <li class="usidebar-index">index</li>

<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're supplying a block to link_to, the (normal) first argument of the link text is no longer required.

So I'm guessing you want this instead:

```
<%= link_to {:controller => 'user', :action => 'resume'}, :class => is_active?('index') do %>
  <li class="usidebar-index">index</li>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thank you.But there are some syntaxError in User#index.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<%= link_to content_tag(:li, :class => "usidebar-index"),{ :controller => "user", :action => "resume" },  :class => is_active?("index") do %>
```

Although, it's quite odd to see an `li` within an `a` tag. Usually it's the other way around.