# How to use Rails, form_for, and Bootstrap to generate properly nested <form>

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-2, form-for

I've inherited some old Rails 2.3 code. I want to use the standard rails `<%= form_for %>` and `<%= remote_form_for %>` helpers.  I also want to use Twitter Bootstrap, and have the `<label>` `<input>` be properly nested in the Bootstrap classed divs, like so:

```
<div class="control-group">
  <label class="control-label" for="inputEmail">Email</label>
  <div class="controls">
    <input type="text" id="inputEmail" placeholder="Email">
  </div>
</div>
```

Is there a good gem/method to do this? We have TONS of `<form>` elements in our app, so ideally I'd love to have a helper method or gem to handle this for me.

I've previously used twitter-bootstrap-rails gem, but its asset-pipeline driven.  We've considered adding the asset pipeline to Rails 2 using this method: http://pivotallabs.com/giving-rails-2-the-asset-pipeline/ but would like to consider solutions that don't rely on this as well.

Comment: Can you use a block of code to wrap the form? Similar to this answer?  http://stackoverflow.com/a/1086429/836450

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went ahead and forked a gem and backported it for Rails 2.3.  It allows perfect Bootstrap 2.3 markup:

https://github.com/Lordnibbler/twitter_bootstrap_form_for/blob/rails-2.3/