# Wrapping Link_to around contents in Rails

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to wrap a link around an li in my rails app, and I thought the following would work:

```
     <%= link_to project_path(remix) do %>
      <li>
          <div class="remix-list-image"><%=link_to image_tag(remix.default_image.image_path_url(:preview), :class=>"img-polaroid"), project_path(remix)  %></div>
          <div class="remix-list-title"><%=link_to remix.title, project_path(remix) %> by <%= link_to remix.author, user_path(remix.user) %></div>
      </li>
      <% end %>
```

But it's producing the following html:

```
<a href="/projects/206">
</a>
<li>
     <a href="/projects/206"></a>
     <div class="remix-list-image">
        <a href="/projects/206"></a>
        <a href="/projects/206"><img alt="Preview_2013-06-18_08.25.02" class="img-polaroid" src=""></a>
      </div>
      <div class="remix-list-title"><a href="/projects/206">Video Test Remix</a> by <a href="/users/tiff">tiff</a>
      </div>
</li>
```

I expect it to do something like the following:

```
<a href ="/projects/206">
<li>...</li>
</a>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I wrap link\_to around some html ruby code?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1086360/how-do-i-wrap-link-to-around-some-html-ruby-code)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you looking at the Inspector, or the actual generated code? If the former, it's probably what the browser is interpreting your HTML as, rather than what it actually is in the source code.

The reason it's wonky is because you can't put an `li` into an anchor in that way; the only thing a `ul` or `ol` is allowed to contain is an `li`. Change the code to this, and it should work:

```
 <li>
   <%= link_to project_path(remix) do %>
      <div class="remix-list-image"><%=link_to image_tag(remix.default_image.image_path_url(:preview), :class=>"img-polaroid"), project_path(remix)  %></div>
      <div class="remix-list-title"><%=link_to remix.title, project_path(remix) %> by <%= link_to remix.author, user_path(remix.user) %></div>
    <% end %>
 </li>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help!  I was looking at the inspector, not the source (which seemed to be correct).

Comment: interesting...seems like nesting a div in a link is not possible in anything but html-5...good to know!