# Change character color for Bootstrap class navbar-brand

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to change the color of my navbar brand name from this:
[image]

To this :

[image]

For any text within a paragraph, for example, I use this **html** code:

```html
<span style="color: #e74c3c">P</span>aper<span style="color: #e67e22">S</span>tack</h1>
```

However I am not sure how to do it as I used embedded **Ruby** code for my navbar brand name

```
<%= link_to 'PaperStack', root_path, class: "navbar-brand" %>
```

Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can include the spans in your link_to text, just call `html_safe` on the string.

```
<%= link_to '<span style="color: #e74c3c">P</span>aper<span style="color: #e67e22">S</span>'.html_safe, root_path, class: "navbar-brand" %>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<%= link_to root_path do %>
  html-code-here
<% end %>
```

As answered here: [How do I wrap link_to around some html ruby code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1086360/how-do-i-wrap-link-to-around-some-html-ruby-code)

Answer (score 0):

How about a hepler method:

```
def navbar_brand_text
  content_tag :span, 'P', class: 'letter-p' +
  content_tag :span, 'aper', class: 'paper' +
  content_tag :span, 'S', class: 'letter-s' +
  content_tag :span, 'tack', class: 'stack'
end
```

Then you could use it like this:

```
<%= link_to navbar_brand_text, root_path, class: 'navbar-brand' %>
```

Then use CSS to stype the spans:

```
.letter-p {
  color: #foo;
}
/* etc... */
```

Comment: The helper method `def navbar_brand_text
  content_tag :span, 'P', class: 'letter-p' +
  content_tag :span, 'aper', class: 'paper' +
  content_tag :span, 'S', class: 'letter-s' +
  content_tag :span, 'tack', class: 'stack'
end` where should I put this method in my rails app?