# How to use correctly link_to and its block in rails to incorporate html tags within?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

I have this block of code :

```
<div class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-light navbar-lewagon">
  <a class="navbar-brand d-flex align-items-center" href="#">
    <%= image_tag "pokeball.png", alt: "Pokeball" %>
    <h2>Cocktails Mania</h2>
  </a>
</div>
```

And I'd like to transform my `<a>` tag to a `link_to`. I tried with this code but it doesn't work... Anyone has a solution?

```
<div class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-light navbar-lewagon">
  <% link_to root_path, class: "navbar-brand d-flex align-items-center" do %>
    <%= image_tag "pokeball.png", alt: "Pokeball" %>
    <h2>Cocktails Mania</h2>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Thanks

Comment: you missed '=' in link_to 
<%= link_to .... %>

Comment: Omg, such a noob mistake, I read my code ten times... Thx for your help !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `link_to` needs to be rendered, for that reason it is not being displayed then  you are missing the `=` which makes it render.

See [How do I wrap link_to around some html ruby code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1086360/how-do-i-wrap-link-to-around-some-html-ruby-code)

and

[link_to Api reference](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/link_to)

Comment: you have `<% link_to root_path`. must be `<%= link_to root_path`

Comment: @Yshmarov not me but the OP, but exactly that is the problem !