# Why my link_to is not showing on the page?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

For some reason, I can not see the link. I can see the `<h3>` tag around it on the browser but no link to be found.
There is no error, and I double-checked that the contact path exists. What am I doing wrong?

```
<h1>Hello to the my app</h1>
<h3><% link_to 'test', ask_path %></h3>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<% link_to 'test', ask_path %>
```

move to

```
<%= link_to 'test', ask_path %>
```

you need `<%=` to show something on the page, not just execute ruby

Answer (score 0):

The link_to needs to be rendered, for that reason it is not being displayed then you are missing the = which makes it render.

[See How do I wrap link_to around some html ruby code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1086360/how-do-i-wrap-link-to-around-some-html-ruby-code)

and

[link_to Api reference](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/link_to)