# Can you make a CSS <header> element into a link?

Tags: html, css, styles, background-image

I have a site that has a `<header>` which is styled so that the header graphic is the `background-image`. I would like to have the header link to the home page.

Is there an elegant way to do this that will allow me to keep it as a header with a `background-image`?

**CSS:**

```
#header {
  background-image: url('../images/header.jpg');
  height: 144px;
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: <div ID='header' onclick="location.href='homepage.html'">Your Header</div>


You can also check out the following link for detail:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1685078/how-do-you-make-a-div-tag-into-a-link

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Background images are not linkable. The "proper" way to go about this would be to have an `<a>` element that has the appropriate `href`, and put the `background-image` to that. Use CSS to make the `<a>` tak up the needed space.

Comment: @MattBrand Also, remember to apply display:block; to the anchor tag so that it becomes a block-level element instead of inline (so that it takes up the space of the set width/height).

Comment: @MattBrand - If this solution worked for you, please mark it as the accepted solution by clicking the checkmark next to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your question refers to `<header>` element but the CSS code uses a class selector `#header`. Technically you could have `<header class=header>`, but that would be rather pointless, and `#header` suggests that the actual markup has `<div class=header>`.

Both a `<header>` element and a `<div>` element can be placed inside an `<a>` element, as far as actual browser behavior is considered. HTML specifications have traditionally disallowed such constructs, but HTML5 CR allows any “flow content” inside `<a>`.

If the header is really just one image (as a background image), then it would appear to be more natural to use just an `a` element and set the background image directly on it. However, this reduces accessibility, because there is no way to specify alternate text for a background image, so to screen readers and to browsers with image loading disabled, there would be a link with no content, no link text. Therefore, if the header should be a link, it is better to use a content image, e.g.

```
<header>
<a href="./"><img src=hdr.png alt="ACME Company" border=0></a>
</header>
```

(However, a content image forces the minimal page width to the width of the image. This is not always desirable, but that’s a different story and different question.)

Answer (score 0):

Anchors are now block elements in HTML5, so they can wrap block elements like `h1`, `p` and `div`. They are not, however, meant to wrap `header`, `article`, `nav`, `section` etc.

You could use JavaScript to assign an `onClick` event to the header element if you do not have access to the markup or CSS, but that of course requires JavaScript in order to work.

Instead you will need wrap the contents of the `header` with an `a` and assign it a `href` to your homepage. You can then style the link (make sure you set it to `display: block`) with a background image and other CSS.

Comment: "They are not, however, meant to wrap header, article, nav, section etc." - citation needed.

Comment: Well there is no reason why it couldn't wrap, but I have yet to meet any developers who do...

Answer (score 0):

I do it like this when using a separate style sheet.

Original css header tag

```
    <div id="header">

    </div>
```

Added span to make header a link

```
    <span><a href="http://www.yourwebsitename.com/">
    <div id="header">

    </div></a></span>
```