# How to make an HTML class containing links a link?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

The image and caption, in class `story` has two different links. Image points to one location and link to another.

I need to make whole class `story` into a link.

```
<div class="story">
<a href="link"> <img src="linkforimage"></a> 
<a href="link2">Caption for image </a>
</div>
```

I need a solution like this:

```
<a href="link">
  <div class="story">
    <a href="link"> <img src="linkforimage"></a> 
    <a href="link2">Caption for image </a>
  </div>
</a>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4465956/4028085

Comment: Did you try `onclick()`?

Comment: wrap your `div` in an `a` tag...

Comment: So you already have the solution? Can you clarify a bit more as to your desired result?

Comment: Try [looking here][1] for using JS or jQuery


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1685078/how-do-you-make-a-div-tag-into-a-link

Comment: I have tried wraping whole class in <a href> but it doesnt working. Need a solution in Js, will try onclick. Thanks

Comment: Do you mean "image points to one location and **caption** to another."?

Comment: You said: *I need to make whole class "story" as **a** link.* So do you need ONE link or TWO links?

Comment: Image points to one link, caption to another. I need to make image to be linked to the same location. I know it sounds stupid, cause I can just change link, but I use embedly platform which parses image from the "link" which is original article. Link2 is a same article on my web site.

Comment: With onclick(), image still points to "link", where I need it to point to "link2"

Answer (score 2):

Nesting `a` tags is a bad idea. I would use a delegate here. Have a wrapper `a` tag and in JS check which source `span` was clicked.

*html*

```
<a href="#" class="story">
    <span data-href="link"><img src="linkforimage"/></span> 
    <span data-href="link2">Caption for image</span>
</a>
```

*js* (jquery based)

```
$('.story').on('click', 'span', function() {
  document.location.href= $(this).data('href');
});
```

Comment: The problem I am facing right now is that I am using embedly platform, where image comes from <a href>. So, I just post <a href> with link and image are parsed from the link by embedly. But, that ahref takes user to original web site. Caption takes user to the page with that content on my web site. I need to make <a href> of caption to the whole div. Hope you can help me out, thanks.

Comment: In that case I'd just JavaScript to rewrite the href of the image link. `$('.story a').attr('href', 'link')`. This sets the link of all `a` tags within the `story` div to the right link

Answer (score 0):

You can't have `anchor` tag inside `anchor` tag.
You can use onclick method to achieve your goal.

```
<div onClick="window.open(link);" class="story">
<a> <img src="linkforimage"></a> 
<a onClick="window.open(link2); event.stopPropagation();" >Caption for image </a>
</div>
```

EDIT [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yb8a6f94/)

Comment: Tried this, but when user clicks on image, it goes to "link" where I need to make whole class "story" to be "link2" same as caption.

Comment: The problem I am facing right now is that I am using embedly platform, where image comes from <a href>. So, I just post <a href> with link and image are parsed from the link by embedly. But, that ahref takes user to original web site. Caption takes user to the page with that content on my web site. I need to make <a href> of caption to the whole div. Hope you can help me out, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Clarifying the problem I am facing right now is that I am using embedly platform, where image comes from . So, I just post  with link and image are parsed from the link by embedly. But, that ahref takes user to original web site. Caption takes user to the page with that content on my web site. I need to make  of caption to the whole div.

So, I found the answer with CSS,
I just added:  style="  pointer-events: none;cursor: default;" on the link with image and style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="window.location='link'" on a class "story" in div.