# Why href cannot clickable when wrap inside div

Tags: html, css

Help! I try to create a mobile navigation bar at the bottom but for some reason my href link cannot be clicked. When I try to inspect the element with Google Chrome it kept select div instead of the href link

[Interface Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ZYA4.png)

My code

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".home1").click(function() {
    alert($(this).attr("navi"));
  });
});
```

```css
.mobile_navigator {
  display: block;
  /*overflow: hidden;*/
  background-color: #0e8ce4;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 60px;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
  box-shadow: 0 -5px 15px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)!important;
}

.mobile_navigator div {
  width: 20%;
  float: left;
  padding: 8px 0 8px 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  cursor: default;
  z-index: 10;
  position: relative;
}

.mobile_navigator div i {
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 13px 0 5px 0;
}

.mobile_navigator span {
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  font-size: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="mobile_navigator">
  <div navi="#">
    <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
    <span>MENU</span>
  </div>
  <div navi="#">
    <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
    <span>MENU</span>
  </div>
  <div href="index.jsp?navi=home" navi="#" class="nav_active home1">
    <i class="fa fa-home"></i>
    <span>HOME</span>
  </div>
  <div navi="#">
    <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
    <span>FEED</span>
  </div>
  <div navi="#">
    <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
    <span>PROFILE</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

When i try to alert when ever the link is clicked, javascript failed to execute because no link had been clicked

Comment: why does a div have an href? You should be using anchors, not divs.

Comment: I think the JSX  needs a parent element. Additionally would you not want to surround your href with a div and not make your div into one.

Comment: Maybe you're looking for `<a>` with `href` attribute, not `<div>` with `navi` attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just replace the `div` tags with an anchor tag and you should be fine. However to address your issue, the problem was having `pointer-events: none;` inside your div that's why your events generated by pointers were not getting triggered inside Javascript.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#home1").click(function() {
    alert($(this).attr("navi"));
  });
});
```

```css
.mobile_navigator {
  display: block;
  /*overflow: hidden;*/
  background-color: #0e8ce4;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 60px;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
  box-shadow: 0 -5px 15px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) !important;
}

.mobile_navigator a {
  width: 20%;
  float: left;
  padding: 8px 0 8px 0;
  cursor: default;
  z-index: 10;
  position: relative;
  text-decoration: none
}

.mobile_navigator a i {
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 13px 0 5px 0;
}

.mobile_navigator span {
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  font-size: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="mobile_navigator">
  <a navi="#">
    <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
    <span>MENU</span>
  </a>
  <a navi="#">
    <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
    <span>MENU</span>
  </a>
  <a navi="YOUR CONTENT HERE" id="home1" href="index.jsp?navi=home">
    <i class="fa fa-home"></i>
    <span>HOME</span>
  </a>
  <a navi="#">
    <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
    <span>FEED</span>
  </a>
  <a navi="#">
    <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
    <span>PROFILE</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks.. Finally it work like a charm. Now I can continue

Comment: Awesome @Zero99

Answer (score 4):

Use [a validator](https://validator.nu/).

`href` is an attribute that appears on `<a>` elements.

You cannot apply it to arbitrary elements (e.g. your `<div>`) to turn them into links.

Use an `<a>` element (either instead of the `<div>` or around it).

Answer (score 1):

Use `href` in an anchor `(<a></a>)` tag as `href` is not a general atrribute. You can nest an `<a href="LINK"></a>` inside your `<div>` tag.

Though you can see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1685097) answer to make a link using the `<div>` tag using Javascript and jQuery.