# Need to make a clickable <div> button

Tags: css, html

Kindly go through this link and notice the solution given by "thepeer": https://stackoverflow.com/a/3494108

I am having trouble understanding his solution. Let me illustrate with the example of a webpage that I am trying to build. I am using HTML5 to build "buttons". Now since these buttons are actually DIV objects, I somehow need to make them "clickable" which would lead the viewer to another page, and that too, without making the "link" visible. The div object should act as a button and **I don't intend to "include" a hypertext-ed line of text inside** the button.

I think the solution given by "thepeer" does exactly that but i am unable to understand his solution and implement it. Perhaps a very small example would benefit me.

Suppose this is the button that i want to make :

```html
<div id="music" class="nav">
    Music I Like 
    <span id="hyperspan"><a href="Music.html"></a></span>
</div>
```

And here's the CSS as "thepeer" suggested :

```
.hyperspan
{
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    left:0;
    top:0;
    z-index:1;
}
```

Now, obviously, I misunderstood his solution and hence my above attempt is incorrect. I don't want to resort to javascript so please help me! Sorry for my noobish-ness.

Comment: thepeer's solution is a trick to make an <a> element "expand" to the whole div it's in, without covering the rest of the content of the div. But I believe you don't want an <a> element, right? If you really want a button, why not use a <button>?

Comment: @MrLister Because I think the idea was no code, just a link.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

There are two solutions posted on that page. The one with lower votes I would recommend if possible.

If you are using HTML5 then it is perfectly valid to put a `div` inside of `a`. As long as the div doesn't also contain some other specific elements like other link tags.

```
<a href="Music.html">
  <div id="music" class="nav">
    Music I Like
  </div>
</a>
```

The solution you are confused about actually makes the link as big as its container div. To make it work in your example you just need to add `position: relative` to your div. You also have a small syntax error which is that you have given the span a class instead of an id. You also need to put your span inside the link because that is what the user is clicking on. I don't think you need the `z-index` at all from that example.

```
div { position: relative; }
.hyperspan {
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    left:0;
    top:0;
}

<div id="music" class="nav">Music I Like 
    <a href="http://www.google.com"> 
        <span class="hyperspan"></span>
    </a>   
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rBKXM/9

When you give `absolute` positioning to an element it bases its location and size after the first parent it finds that is relatively positioned. If none, then it uses the document. By adding `relative` to the parent div you tell the span to only be as big as that.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response.

http://jsfiddle.net/rBKXM/2/

I tried editing the hyperlink to "www.google.com" but it still remains "unclickable". Why is that?

Comment: Woops, didn't see that problem. The span needs to be inside the link because that is what you are clicking on!

Comment: Exactly What I had wanted! Thank you so much mrtsherman! I hope you have a great day! How do you thank people here? :D

Comment: Just a comment that says thank-you is great. Make sure you accept the answer by ticking the checkmark. If you like SO make sure you read the FAQ and help some other people out too! http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: And I still don't understand why you can't use a <button> instead of a <div>.

Comment: @MrLister But isn't using the <button> tag to use as a hyperlink would mean resorting to script to achieve the linking purpose? If not, then I guess I could use <button> but if that's not the case, won't it affect the SEO/Accessibility just like "thepeer" had suggested earlier in the link that I linked in the OP? Correct me if I am wrong and thank you for your time.

Answer (score 29):

Just use an `<a>` by itself, set it to `display: block;` and set `width` and `height`. Get rid of the `<span>` and `<div>`. This is the semantic way to do it. There is no need to wrap things in `<divs>` (or any element) for layout. That is what CSS is for.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ThinkingStiff/89Enq/

HTML:

```
<a id="music" href="Music.html">Music I Like</a>
```

CSS:

```
#music {
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    display: block;
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 40px;
    text-decoration: none;
    width: 100px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Your solution is perfect! Thank you! The only reason I was using <div> tag to achieve this result was because I wanted to animate and transform using CSS3, the div object. But as I just tried, it works just as well on your solution! Amazing!

I'd choose your solution as best but I guess my original question could seem a bit misleading to many answerers as it suggests that i want a solution which caters to divs. 

But of course, for my own purpose, your solution is perfect. Thanks!

Comment: You can accept whatever answer you feel solves your problem best and you can edit your question with new information. You can also upvote as many answers as you find helpful. Glad it worked for you.

Comment: but then how do you do tricks like making the whole screen a button