# HREF="" automatically adds to current page URL (in PHP). Can't figure it out

Tags: php, html

Longtime reader of stackoverflow but first question.

I'm working with Wordpress (specifically thesis theme) in the custom_functions.php file and am finding for some reason  is automatically adding the current page url. For example this code is to query the database and then loop through outputting each product in it's own div:

```
$result = db_connection($query);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { ?>
    <div class="box"><a href="">
        <img src="http://www.electricbikehub.co.nz<?php echo $row['product_root_directory']         . $row['mid_size_image'] ?>">
        <h2><?php echo $row['name']?></h2>
        <p><?php echo $row['description_brief'];?></p>
        <p><span class="multiple_product_red"><span class="multiple_product_linethrough">RRP: <?php echo $row['list_price']; ?>.</span> Our discounted price: <?php echo $row['our_price']; ?>. Includes delivery and GST.</span></p>
        </a>
    </div>
<?php } ?>
```

As you can see 3rd line says href="" but the actual link being generated is the current page (in this case 'http://www.electricbikehub.co.nz/?page_id=1192'). If I add anything in the href, such as href="something" it will just add it to the end, ie http://www.electricbikehub.co.nz/?page_id=1192something.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Does it do the same thing if you put a full url in the href starting with http like http://something.com?

Comment: That doesn't sounds right. Pics or it didn't happen.

Comment: I can't quite figure out your question... what _do_ you want in the href attribute?

Comment: I think I figured it out thanks to wescrow. As I said below if I did href="www.google.com" it would just append it to the end of the root domain name (ie www.electricbikehub.co.nz/www.google.com). But if I added the 'http://' it would be fine. That was my problem...

Answer (score 53, accepted):

This is how a browser interprets and empty href. It assumes you want to link back to the page that you are on. This is the same as if you dont assign an action to a `<form>` element.

If you add any word in the href it will append it to the current page unless you:

- Add a slash `/` to the front of it telling it to append it to your base url e.g. `http://www.whatever.com/something`
- add a `#` sign in which case it is an in-page anchor
- or a valid URL

**EDIT:** It was suggested that I add a link to help clarify the situation. I found the following site that I think does a really good job explaining the `href` attribute of anchor tags and how it interprets URL paths. It is not incredibly technical and very human-readable. It uses lots of examples to illustrate the differences between the path types: http://www.mediacollege.com/internet/html/hyperlinks.html

Comment: Yes, the asker realizes that. It's the non-empty href they're asking about.

Comment: not sure the asker does realize this. It looks like hobbs doesnt know why an empty href is doing anything. or why a non relative or absolute "something" is doing what it is doing. I think wescrows response helps to clarify. Maybe not in full, but still is a good explanation for part of it.

Comment: Added more information in an attempt to better answer the OP's question.

Comment: Thanks wescrow! I think that explains what I was doing wrong. What was confusing me was if I put:
<a href=”www.google.com”> it would append it to my root domain so it would end up being:
www.electricbikehub.co.nz/www.google.com
But if I put <a href=”http://www.google.com”> it would be just fine…
I can’t believe I didn’t know it worked like that. Is this normal?

Comment: Evan, that's not right. You would need to put <a href="HTTP://www.google.com">

Comment: @wescrow, may I suggest linking to the [Resolving URLs section of the HTML spec](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/urls.html#resolving-urls) (particularly the end of the section)? It goes into a bit more detail and is directly from the spec.

Comment: Ben, yeah that's what I meant to write... Must be tired... Thanks for everyone's help!

Comment: @bfrohs I have added a link that helps explain the situation better. However, I felt that the page you suggested was too technical and too hard to read. Although, I would suggest that it would be a good read after the OP had a firm grasp on the subject.

Comment: adding / changes url to localhost/http://www.google.com and adding // changes url to http//www.google.com , so what to do to get proper url?

Comment: @RazaAhmed you are god, adding // worked perfectly I think this should be the selected answer!

Answer (score 25):

Add http:// in front of url

Incorrect

```
<a href="www.example.com">www.example.com</span></p>
```

Correct

```
<a href="http://www.example.com">www.example.com</span></p>
```

Comment: Why does this solution work even when the correct URL is `https://www.example.com`, not `http://www.example.com`?

Comment: A more agnostic value that won't force a specific schema is `//www.example.com`. Nowadays everything should be with TLS, but you never know, it can be useful for flexibility in a development environment without having to setup a certificate.

Answer (score 10):

if you want to redirect it to some other url lets google.com then make your like as 
    [happy to help other says rikin](//google.com) `<a href="//google.com">happy to help other says rikin</a>`
 this will remove self site url form the href.

Answer (score 3):

You can just put // in front of $yourUrl in href:

```
<a href="//<?=$yourUrl?>"></a>
```

Comment: "//" means file. It will treat url as file url.

Answer (score 2):

A solution that works no matter if you are developing on a local server or live is to 
add "//" in front of your link. This will effectivly remove the URL of the site you are currently on.

**Example:**

```
<a href="www.google.com">Google.com</a>
```

This will in output http://localhost/mySite/currentPage/www.google.com

What you should do instead is this:

```
<a href="//www.google.com">Google.com</a>
```

This will output [www.google.com](https://www.google.com/)

Comment: I receive `about:blank#blocked`

Answer (score 1):

You do realize this is the default behavior, right? if you add /something the results would be different.

you can do a number of things to prevent default behavior.

### `href="#"`:

Will do nothing but anchor - not the best solution since it may jump to page top.

```html
<a href="#">
```

### `href="javascript:void(0);"`

Will do nothing at all and is perfectly legit.

```html
<a href="javascript:void(0);"></a>
```

### `href="your-actual-intended-link"` (*Best*)

obviously the best.

```html
<a href="<your-actual-intended-link>"></a>
```

---

If you don't want an `a` tag to go somewhere, why use an `a` tag at all?

Comment: The solution href="javascript:void(0);" did the trick for me. Thanks!

Comment: Using ' href="#" ' will kick you out to the site root if you're using the MVC paradigm.

Answer (score 0):

eI also have the same issue with that, it's just like other answers from before but then when I tried using that it still adding more and more to the URL. So I add something into my code.

from this :

```
<a href="//<?= $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] ?>something/about">about</a>
```

to :

```
<a href="///<?= $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] ?>something/about">about</a>
```

if you notice I add one backslash "/" on the href="///" and not only using two backslashes

Answer (score -2):

In any case, your code will generate invalid markup: You shouldn't wrap block contents in a link.  tags don't work like this. If you want this effect you should use js or create an absolutely positioned link above the content (z-index). More on this here: [Make a div into a link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/796087/make-a-div-into-a-link).

You should make sure to validate your code when it renders: http://validator.w3.org

Comment: Actually, no, that isn't correct. See [HTML Spec](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/text-level-semantics.html#the-a-element). "The a element may be wrapped around entire paragraphs, lists, tables, and so forth, even entire sections, so long as there is no interactive content within (e.g. buttons or other links)."

Comment: Interesting, this appears to be doctype dependent. According to w3.org this is only allowed for HTML5. HTML4 and XHTML doctypes will result in an error: "you have attempted to put a block-level element (such as "<p>" or "<table>") inside an inline element (such as "<a>", "<span>", or "<font>"). " I'm glad they're changing this (it never made sense to me), but at least within the doctype that WP ships with (XHTML 1.0 Transitional) this is still invalid. Thanks for the heads-up, though. This is good to know.

Comment: Technically, yes, but browsers use the same parser for XHTML 1.0 Transitional as they do for HTML5, unless you specifically set up your server to return the correct headers. Also, while WordPress's default theme is XHTML 1.0 Transitional, other themes may not be (It's an easy change to use XHTML5 instead in a theme) and it may change in the future. If you add an overview of what we've talked about in the comments to your answer, I'd be glad to +1 it :)

Answer (score -4):

Use this:

```
<a href="<?php echo(($_SERVER['HTTPS'] ? 'https://' : 'http://').$_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]); ?>">Whatever</a>
```

It will create a HREF using the current URL...

Comment: I'd be very careful using this, unless you force path rewrites with .htaccess or PHP (code injection). Also, you should include `($_SERVER['HTTPS'] ? 'https://' : 'http://').` at the beginning since `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']` only returns `www.somedomain.com` (see [$_SERVER documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php))

Comment: Indeed, but if he haves a HTTP website, he just haves to include the HTTP:// or HTTPS:// before the PHP code... The protocol is not changing frequently!

Comment: No, but when it does, if you include that code, he won't have to find each and change it manually (and redirects for every link can increase page load times). Either way though, it's a good idea to at least mention in your answer that the http(s?):// is required as well as note that escaping of `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` is necessary.