# How to work with ui-sref in Angular UI Router and NodeJS

Tags: angularjs, node.js, redirect, angular-ui-router, ui-sref

I am at the url path `http://localhost:3000/u#/` and I click on an `href` link to go to `http://localhost:3000/u#/76457898/profile`. I need this to happen without sending a request to server.
But that only happens the second time I click on the `href` link.

The first time I click on it, I get myself redirected back to `http://localhost:3000/u#/76457898`. Only the second time I click on it the page is not redirected and I get only the `users.profile` state takes the `<div ui-view><div>`.

The `http://localhost:3000/u#/` takes me to the same page as `http://localhost:3000/u#/76457898`.

**HTML**

```
<a href="{{goToUIState('users.profile', user.userId)}}">
    <!--stuff-->
</a>
```

**AngularJS with Angular UI Router**

```
.state('users', {
    url: '/:userId',
    abstract: true,
    resolve: {
        user: ['$cookies', '$stateParams', '$http', 'localStorageService',
            function($cookies, $stateParams, $http, localStorageService) {
                var uid = $cookies.uid || localStorageService.get('uid');
                return $http.get('/api/users/' + uid).success(function (resp) {
                    localStorageService.set('uid', uid);
                    return resp;
                })
            }
        ]
    },
    views: {
        'home': {
            templateUrl: '/partials/user/index.html',
            controller: ['$scope','$state', 'user', '$stateParams', function($scope, $state, user, $stateParams) {
                $scope.user = user.data;

                //dynamic ui-sref do not work, so creating a function to do that with $state.href()
                $scope.goToUIState = function(state, userId) {
                    return $state.href(state, {userId: userId});
                }
                $state.go('users.home');
            }]
        }
    }
})

.state('users.home', {
    url: '',
    templateUrl: '/partials/user/users.home.html',
    controller: [$scope', 'user', function($scope, user) {
        $scope.user = user.data;
    }]

})

.state('users.profile', {
    url: '/profile',
    templateUrl: '/partials/user/users.profile.html',
    controller: ['$scope', '$rootScope', 'user', '$http', 'fileUpload',
        function($scope, $rootScope, user, $http, fileUpload) {
            $scope.user = user.data;
            //stuff
        }]
})
```

Could somebody help me understand the reason behind why do I get the desired second only when I click the `href` link second time and how do I resolve this?

I am using NodeJS/ExpressJS on the server side.

Comment: I'm confused by your html. Should you not be using something like the following [as per the docs](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.directive:ui-sref)? `<a ui-sref="users.profile({ userId: user.userId })">{{ xxx }}</a>`

Comment: @DavidSpence: Even when I use `<a ui-sref="users.profile({ userId: user.userId })">{{ xxx }}</a>` I have to click twice to get to `http://localhost:3000/u#/76457898/profile`. The first time I click, it gets me at `http://localhost:3000/u#/76457898`, and when the second time I click it finally takes me the desired `http://localhost:3000/u#/76457898/profile`.

Comment: @DavidSpence: The issue somehow seems to be with the dynamic binding part. https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/395. So for binding something dynamically I had to use the html the way I did.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you're getting this problem because of the function used inside `href` attribute. I had a similar problem some time ago (I was also developing an app and I was using ui-router). The problem was in using href inside  tag.

I think [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8764288/href-automatically-adds-to-current-page-url-in-php-cant-figure-it-out) migth be helpful. It's important to know how browser interprets empty `href` attribute.

Try to use your function in other tag, let's say make a menu inside `ul` list and `ui` elements (`ng-click` directive). It helped in my case.