# PHP page name appending at the start of anchor link

Tags: php

I am currently working on `home.php` where I have the following anchor link echo'd:

```
<a href='#?id=$thought_id' class='toggle-comment' data-id='$thought_id' style='padding-left: 5px;'> Comments ($num_of_comments) </a>
```

Now, when I hover over the `Comments` anchor, I get the id of the `thought` fine. It's just that when I hover over the link, or when I click the link, the url reads:

```
http://localhost/home.php#?id=210
```

So, `210` is the ID of the thought the comments anchor is assigned to, which works. But I do not understand why the file name is appending to the anchor link when it hasn't been defined to do so.

Even when I put `<a href='#'>` The URL still reads `http://localhost/home.php#`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HREF="" automatically adds to current page URL (in PHP). Can't figure it out](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8764288/href-automatically-adds-to-current-page-url-in-php-cant-figure-it-out)

Answer (score 0):

Your browser is going to show you the full, canonical URL (including the anchor) when you hover over a link.  It's the same link that will be copied to your clipboard if you right-click it and choose "Copy Link Location".

Comment: Can you please explain in your answer what is a canonical URL? You described what it displayed but you didn't explained why.

Comment: When you use the "Copy Link Location" function, what you want is a complete URL of the page (and possibly anchor location) of the link.  So if you're on `http://www.example.com/index.html` , then even if the HTML code is `<a href="#foo">`, the link you want copied to your clipboard is `http://www.example.com/index.html#foo`.  That's the canonical URL, and that's what will be copied to your clipboard.  And that's also what will be displayed on the status bar.  It doesn't **have** to be that way, but all major web browsers have decided that it's probably a very good idea.

Comment: I don't see how it explains why the user has the link `/home.php#?id=210` and not just `/#?id=210 `, sorry.

Comment: He is working on the server "localhost" on the file "home.php" and pointing to an anchor named "#?id=210" .  So the full URL is `http://localhost/home.php#?id=$thought_id` .  If he was working on the index page of the server (for example `index.html`), then it would be `http://localhost/index.html#?id=$thought_id`.  And since index.html is the index page, that can be shortened to `http://localhost/#?id=$thought_id`

Comment: @DavidWhite - Sorry for the late reply.  I think I understand what you're conveying, but I am unable to understand one thing, I have the exact same anchor link (and connected code) on `profile_page.php` and `hearted_thoughts.php`. The anchor link on these pages work, they do not append the current page URL to to content within the href, then why does this only occur on `home.php`?