# How to prevent canonical URL's

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have an anchor link on `home.php` which goes link this:

```
<a href='#?id=$thought_id' class='toggle-comment' data-id='$thought_id' '> Comments ($num_of_comments) </a>
```

When hovering over this anchor link, I expect to see results like this:

```
localhost/#?id=210
```

But what I am getting it this:

```
localhost/home.php#?id=211
```

I have seen a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8764288/href-automatically-adds-to-current-page-url-in-php-cant-figure-it-out): But, having applied what the best answer suggests, I still get the same results. I also have the exact same anchor link present on `profile_page.php` and it works perfectly there.

The anchor link is not meant to go anywhere, on click, it dynamically enlarges the div below it, showing comments.

**Edit**:

**How anchor link works**:

1. when clicked, the anchor link expands the div below it. When clicked, this div appears: `echo "<div id='toggleComment$thought_id' class='new_comment'>";`
2. Then for each new comment added to this `thought`, another div is echo'd

   `<div class='new_comm' id='thoughtId".$thought_id."-childId".$comment['id']."'>`

**JavaScript to achieve this**:

```
$(function() {
    $("a.toggle-comment").on("click", function(event) {
        // prevents browser to go to href's #
        event.preventDefault();
        // uses Jquery's data() function to get comment id from link's data-id attribute
        var id = $(this).data('id');       
        // get element by id and toggle display
        var ele = document.getElementById("toggleComment" + id);
        $(ele).toggle();
    });
});
```

**Edit 2**:

Came to a conclusion with Rocki in chat. The issue was that I have the JavaScript defined twice, once in the source code of `home.php` and once in `functions.js` which was also in the `head` of `home.php`. Removed the script from the source code, and code began to function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything behind `#` is interpreted as the hash fragment and not send to the server. Instead your **browser** change the hash fragment for the current page.

RFC 2396: Uniform Resource Identifiers (URI): Generic Syntax

> The character "#" is excluded because it is used to delimit a URI
> from a fragment identifier in URI references (Section 4).

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2396

Comment: Sorry for the late response. I am still failing the understand why this issue occurs on one page and not in the other, where the exact same code is present?

Comment: Is `profile_page.php` included by `index.php`? What the browser shows in the address bar matters.

Comment: Sorry, but what do you mean by included by `index.php`? Also, the only link `index.php` and `home.php` have, is that when a user successfully logs in, it takes them to `home.php` (`header( "Location: home.php" );`)

Comment: A lot of php apps use index.php to dispatch the request to correct handler (Dispatcher / Router Pattern). Simplified Example: `switch($_GET('site')) { case 'home': include('home.php'); break; ... }`

Comment: Hmm, I honestly don't really know what to say, this is the first time I have came across URL routing and dispatching. Also, I don't know if you're asking if I have used either approach in `index.php`. Does this have anything to do with my `.HTACCESS` file?

Comment: No .htaccess files are not related to dispatching / routing (except mod_rewrite for human readable url's).
Does your address bar show `localhost/profile_page.php`? The default behavior (firefox, chrome, ...) should append/change the hash for the current address, thus `localhost/profile_page.php#?id=211`

Comment: So when I go onto `profile_page.php` the URL states `http://localhost/profile_page/conor` (Conor being the username of the user logged in). And when I click onto the `comments` link, the URL stays the same. Would you like to discuss this in chat? I can provide you with a graphical representation of what is happening if that helps?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108835/discussion-between-rocki-and-freddy).

Answer (score 0):

use

```
<a href='/#?id=$thought_id' class='toggle-comment' data-id='$thought_id' '> Comments ($num_of_comments) </a>
```

instead (added / before your url)

Comment: I have tried that, but for some reason, when I click the link then, it logs me out and sends me to `index.php`.

Comment: so you are using some other javascript that has modified something, because normally that's how url works !

Comment: Yes, so as mentioned, when the link is clicked, the div below it expands. I have used JavaScript to achieve this and will update my question to show my JavaScript.