# Add query string to url using anchor link

Tags: javascript, html, anchor

### UPDATE

Sorry my qusetion was unclear i have updated my question

I want to add a query string in the end of url using anchor

For example if i have url

> www.mysite.com/home

And have anchors on this page

```
 <a href='?page=1'>1</a>
 <a href = '?page=2'>2</a>
      .
      .
 <a href = '?page =x'>x</a>
```

When i click on these anchor link it directs me to Url

> www.mysite.com/home?page=x

That what i want , I just want to add query string `page` in the end of the url,

But in the case of

> www.mysite.com/home?category=sports

Or

> www.mysite.com/home?category=music

Then if i click on the same anchor link

It redirects me to

> www.mysite.com/home?page=x

But i want it to direct me to

> www.mysite.com/home?category=sports&page=x

And now if i again on any of those link  like

```
<a href='?page=1'>1</a>
```

Then i want it to direct me to

> www.mysite.com/home?category=sports&page=1

is their any simple solution to do this , Or i have to use any complex javascript code.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

It is simple.

```
var url ="www.mysite.com/home?page=1"; 
var result = url + (url.indexOf('?')== -1 ?  "?page=1" : "&page=1")
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't recommend using this but I think this is the only solution:

```
<a href="Javascript: if (window.location.href.indexOf('page=')==-1) { window.location=(window.location.href+ (window.location.href.toString().indexOf('?')>-1 ? '&page=1': '?page=1'))}">click here</a>
```

Comment: Hey challenger I updated my question , hope now u can understand what i am asking

Comment: mmm, I don't know how to solve this actually, check this link hope it can help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8764288/href-automatically-adds-to-current-page-url-in-php-cant-figure-it-out

Comment: what is id here

Answer (score 0):

window.location.replace(url);

url - is the string you want to open

Answer (score 0):

You have to add all params to the link, like this:

```
<a href='?category=sports&page=1'>1</a>
<a href='?category=sports&page=2'>2</a>
.
.
.
<a href='?category=sports&page=x'>x</a>
```

Comment: their are many categories, Assume i have url `www.mysite.com/home?category=music`

Comment: What if the query parameters are dynamic?