# i am trying to get to the root url in php

Tags: php, html, css, redirect

I have this link in my db.php. I want everytime the dropdown menu is clicked it redirect to the corresponding page.

```
$ROOT_URL = '192.167.1.67/office/';
```

I want to go to this root url on the navigation every time i click on the link.

```
<a href="<?php echo $ROOT_URL; ?>admin/admindashboard.php">Home</a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="addproduct.php">Add Product</a></li>
      <li><a href="product/viewproduct.php">View Product</a></li>
      <li><a href="removedproduct.php">Removed Product</a></li>
    </ul>
```

instead the page is redirecting as

```
192.168.1.67/admin/192.168.1.67/admin/product/addproduct.php
```

How can i solve this problem??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HREF="" automatically adds to current page URL (in PHP). Can't figure it out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8764288/href-automatically-adds-to-current-page-url-in-php-cant-figure-it-out)

Answer (score 0):

use protocol before your url like..

```
$ROOT_URL = 'http://192.167.1.67/office/';
OR if having https $ROOT_URL = 'https://192.167.1.67/office/';
```

Answer (score 0):

If the link points to a local location, you can just use `/` as root.

This, for examples will work:

```
<a href="/office/admin/admindashboard.php">Home</a>
```

If `$ROOT_URL` is dynamic and you want to include the variable, define it as:

```
$ROOT_URL = '/office/';
```

Then you can do:

```
<a href="<?php echo $ROOT_URL; ?>admin/admindashboard.php">Home</a>
```

Also, the links in the list

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
  <li><a href="addproduct.php">Add Product</a></li>
  <li><a href="product/viewproduct.php">View Product</a></li>
  <li><a href="removedproduct.php">Removed Product</a></li>
</ul>
```

point to a relative URL, so when your current URL is `/office`, the links will point to: `/office/addproduct.php`. But if this navigation is also included on a page where the URL is `/some/other/url`, this link will point to: `/some/other/url/addproduct.php`.

Unless you are really sure the HTML with the link will only show at a certain path, try to avoid relative URLs.