# How to make DIV clickable on non-clickable areas?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a `<div>` which contains a few links (`<a>` tags) and other elements in it. I want to have the `<div>` behave like a button, which means whenever the user clicks on every part of it, it should navigate to some link. There are a few solutions like this one:
[Make a div into a link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/796087/make-a-div-into-a-link) I can make it work with jQuery too, however, the problem is that I want the `<a>` tags in the `<div>` to work like before. I couldn't find any solution which makes this possible. How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$('#mydiv a').click(function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Events bubble up, that's what they do.  This is called propagation.  Calling `stopPropagation` on the jQuery event object should prevent that event from bubbling up to your div that contains it.

[jQuery Docs here](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/)

And since the event handler does not `return false`, then the browser default click handling for `<a>` tags will still be fired, which means the `href` is followed as normal.

Check out a working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/Squeegy/2phtM/

Answer (score 1):

I think you need an event handler which determines which element triggered the click - something like this

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(function() {
                $("#links").click(handler);
            })
            function handler(event) {

                var $target = $(event.target);
                if($target.is("#links")) {

                    window.location = "divlocation.htm"
                }
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="links" style="background: yellow">
            <a href="test1.htm">link 1</a><br>
            <a href="test2.htm">link 2</a>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```