# Make link, without "a href" and without JS

Tags: html, css

I want to make my entire `div` a link like the `a` tag. Of course this may be possible with js, but I'm interested in seeing if this is possible to do with only css.

I have this:

```
#my_div {
  width: 200px;
  background-color: #090;
}

#my_div:hover {
  background-color: #0f0;
}
```

Where the page structure is:

```
<div id="my_div"><a href="http://google.com">link</a></div>
```

Comment: whaaaat ??? You're phrase doesn't make sense

Comment: Sorry, right, this is realy stupid question

Comment: I'm not saying it is stupid, I am just saying I didn't understand what you wrote... ;)

Comment: @OTARIKI No, it's not. It's actually a good question, it just needed some better phrasing. I've edited it, so please tell me if I got something wrong...

Comment: @Jon your edited version is right, you understood my question good. But this is answer on my question, where you give me:
`<a href="http://google.com"><div id="my_div"></div></a>` 
and I think this is very easy and also stupid qestion because answers on these questions, should think self :(
So, thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't make an element with CSS, but you can wrap your `div` with an `a` tag instead. It would look like this:

```
<a href="http://google.com"><div id="my_div"></div></a>
```

That makes the entire div a link to whatever your `href` is.

CSS3 does have the `content` property now, but I don't think you can put raw HTML into it. That would be pretty bad security wise if anyone had access to your `.css` files...

Anyways, I think the above solution is the simplest way to achieve what you asked.

Comment: This is actually a terrible suggestion as `div` is not allowed to be nested within inline elements such as `a`.  Making the `a` tag `display: block` or use a different inline tag such as `span` within the `a` and make it `display: block` is the appropriate way to go.

Comment: @cimmanon but if you look at the HTML5 spec, it is allowed...Not saying you're wrong, but it is technically allowable and makes more sense from a design standpoint (IMO).

Answer (score 5):

You can make inline elements act as block level elements by setting their `display` property to `block`:

```
/* Make all a tags that are decedents of the
   element with an id of `my_div` be displayed as block level elements */
#my_div a {
    display: block;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #090;
}
/* Handle the color change on hover */
#my_div a:hover { background-color: #0f0; }
```

You don't actually need the wrapping `div` - you can just target the particular `a` tag directly if you give it a class or id.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
#my_div a {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to set your pseude class to the a tag not to the div:

```
#my_div a:hover { 
    background-color: #0f0; 
}
```

That should do it's work :-)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should check out this question that was posted to stack overflow.
[Make a div into a link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/796087/make-a-div-into-a-link)
It was the first result on Google for how to make a div a link.

Answer (score 0):

Please:

- HTML adds structure to content (e.g. chapters of a book, what is emphasized ...)
- CSS adds what colors/fonts/placement for those items
- Javascript adds makes it interactive.

Comment: That is what it should be, but it is possible to do style with JS and interact with CSS...

Comment: @Jon - Yes, but keep it simple so that you can give the page a fresh look at a drop of a hat. As to JS - some people (eg corporate) have this switched off. They are fossils we know but could be a big customer.

Comment: @jon - Lots are things are possible but one should not do it.

Answer (score 0):

You weren't clear whether you meant without "a href" or without using the "<a" tag.

If, on the offchance you meant the latter, the only other way I can think to make something clickable go someplace is to make it a form submit button.