# How to link a complete DIV container?

Tags: javascript, css, html

i have the following div Container (including a background image).

```
<div class="haus"></div>
```

how can i link this DIV to an url?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Make a div into a link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/796087/make-a-div-into-a-link)

Answer (score 3):

use the `<a>` tag :

```
<a href="">
    <div class="haus"></div>
</a>
```

Comment: Do note that this is only valid under HTML5 though (it'll work under the HTML 4 doctype, but it's not valid HTML).

Comment: Yes maybe pass the <a> in display:block; and remove <div> it's better?

Comment: i set the link, but it is not on right position.
see here: http://schwedenladen.de

in top header the little house and the words i want to link.

Comment: The problem it's your little house is not an single element but integrated on your background-image of the header. The solution is just put a background blue on the header without the image. After put just an image <img/> with your house and the words.

Answer (score 0):

Surround the `div` with the a-link tag

```
<a href="#">
    <div class="haus"></div>
</a>
```

---

Or you can use `onClick`

```
<div onClick="self.location.href='http://www.google.de'" class="haus"></div>
```

---

Or a "experimental" way is to add the div a `<a>` link and call it over jQuery:

```
<div class="haus">
   <a href="#" style="display:none;">link</a>
</div>
```

jQuery Script:

```
$(".myBox").click(function(){
   window.location=$(this).find("a").attr("href"); 
   return false;
});
```

Comment: i set the link, but it is not on right position.
see here: http://schwedenladen.de

in top header the little house and the words i want to link.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty Easy , like this :

```
<a href="htps://www.google.com">
    <div class="haus">
        This is div
    </div>
</a>
```

Working fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/xhGud/4/

Comment: i set the link, but it is not on right position.
see here: http://schwedenladen.de

in top header the little house and the words i want to link.

Answer (score 0):

Use this if you want to keep the next element in the same line

```
<a href="htps://www.google.com">
   <div class="haus" style='display:inline-block'>
    text
   </div>
</a>
```

or just

```
<a href="htps://www.google.com">
   <div class="haus">
    text
   </div>
</a>
```

This is also fine withe some JS work

```
<div onClick="self.location.href='http://www.google.com'" class="haus"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do it the other way around. by making the `a` to take all the div space. [**Live Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/avrahamcool/xhGud/5/)

That way, it will validate under any doctype.

personally I think it's clearer that way. but, its debatable.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="haus">
    <a href="htps://www.google.com">This is link in the div</a>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.haus
{
    background-color: azure;
    height: 50px;
}

.haus a
{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```