# Django - Click on link won't redirect me to the page unless i right click and open in new tab

Tags: python, django

I'm fairly new to django and I'm working on a project
for some reason clicking on my links won't redirect me to the desired page, nothing happens, but i cant open it bu right click > open in new tab
here is my template

**index.html:**

```
<ul class="list">
      {% for movie in all_movies %}
        <li>
          <img src="{{ movie.poster }}" alt="" class="cover" />
          <a href="{% url 'detail' movie.id %}"><p class="title">{{ movie.title }}</p></a>
          {% for genre in movie.genre.all %}
            <p class="genre">{{ genre.genre }} | </p>
          {% endfor %}
        </li>
      {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

**views.py :**

```
def detail(request, movie_id):
   movie = get_object_or_404(Movie, pk=movie_id)
   return render(request, 'movies/detail.html', {'movie': movie})
```

**urls.py :**

```
urlpatterns = [
   # /movies/
   url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
   # /movies/id/
   url(r'^(?P<movie_id>[0-9]+)/$', views.detail, name='detail'),
]
```

i can't find what's wrong with my code, any help would be appreciated!

Comment: More interesting than your Django code is the HTML code rendered.

Comment: i'm trying to make a movie app

Comment: So if you right click and open in a new tab it works as expected? I assume links on other sites work? What happens when you left click?

Comment: Your issue most likely is this: `p` is a block element, and `a` is an inline element. You have nested a block element inside an inline element, which is valid in HTML5, but not valid for HTML/XHTML, Change the ordering, and it should work

Comment: i did change the order but it didnt work, because originally i had the link in the image and that didnt work either

Comment: when i left click nothing happens and yes links on other sites work fine

Comment: Please add the rendered html code.

Comment: Your code is fine, I just tried it and it works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is most likely a JavaScript issue, this has nothing to do with Django. Your Django setup is working fine, I tested it is well.

There is an identical issue faced by someone else [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20724590/a-href-not-working), and it was revealed that JavaScript was the actual issue.

I can't think of any other issues that may cause this.

Comment: turns out it was from the JS file i just removed it all together and the links work fine, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Hi I had exactly the same problem. More precise: Klicking didn't work, and also klicking the wheel didn't work.

I solved it finding out that around the NAV bar I had `<header class="full-header">`. Changing it to `<header class="header">` made everything work.
I have no full-header in my CSS, BTW.

But there is a smooth scrolling script, I discovered now, which was the real origin of the misbehaviour:

```
$(function() {
   $(".full-header nav a").click(function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     $('html,body').scrollTo(this.hash, this.hash);
   });
});
```