# Django - Left Click on the link not working but right click with new tab works

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, nav

I have a DropDown Menu in my Navbar which shows the recent Notifications for the user. The data is coming dynamically from the Database through Django, and every notification is linked to another Page (to access that, I am getting the ID of the Notification and sending that to `views.py`)

My problem is, I **can not left click on the Notification**. I have tried to make lots of changes but still with no result. The links do work if I Right Click on any of them and open them in New Tab.

The `.html` file contains this following code which shows all the notifications,

```
<ul class="setting-area">
                   
                    
                    <li>
                            <a href="#" title="Notification" data-ripple="">
                        
                            <i class="ti-bell"></i>
                            
                            {% if  fetch_notification_count > 2 %}
                            <span class="text-danger"> (2+) </span>
                            {% else %}
                            <span>{{fetch_notification_count}}</span>
                            {% endif %}
                        </a>
                        <div class="dropdowns">
                           
                            <span>{{fetch_notification_count}} New Notifications</span>
                        
                            <ul class="drops-menu">
                                {% for i in  fetch_notification %}
                                <li>
                                    <span><a  href="{% url 'opennotification' i.post_id.id %}" title=""></span>

                                       <div>
                                            {% if i.show_user.User_Image %}
                                            <img class="card-img-top" style=" vertical-align: middle;width: 50px;height: 50px;border-radius: 50%;" src={{ i.show_user.User_Image.url}} alt="">
                                            {% elif t == 1 %} 
                                             <img class="card-img-top" style=" vertical-align: middle;width: 50px;height: 50px;border-radius: 50%;" src={{ i.User_Image.url}} alt="">
                                             {% else %}
                                            <img class="card-img-top" style=" vertical-align: middle;width: 60px;height: 60px;border-radius: 50%;" src="static\images\resources\no-profile.jpg">
                                             
                                             
                                             {% endif %}
                                        
                            
                                        <div class="mesg-meta">
                                            
                                                                        

                                            <h6 >{{i.show_user.Name}}</h6>
                                            
                                            {% if i.notification_type == 'comment' %}
                                            
                                            <span>Commented on your post</span>
                                            {% elif i.notification_type == 'like' %}
                                            <span>Likes your post</span>
                                            {% elif i.notification_type == 'dislike' %}
                                            <span>Dislike your post</span>
                                            {% endif %}
                                            <i>{{i.notification_date | naturaltime}}</i>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </a>
                                    <span class="tag green">New</span>
                                </li>
                                {% endfor %}
                               
                                
                               
                               
                            </ul>
                            <a href="notifications.html" title="" class="more-mesg">view more</a>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                     
                           
                </ul>
```

I have checked many different posts on Stackoverflow and other sites on Google but nothing really worked for me. I found a very similar problem on Stackoverflow, [Django - Click on link won't redirect me to the page unless i right click and open in new tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39402445/django-click-on-link-wont-redirect-me-to-the-page-unless-i-right-click-and-op) according to which the problem is in the Javascript. I have not added any Custom Javascript for my this Notification bar, but there is some script that is being added for styling. I tried to check and delete/modify jQuery functions in that file, however I still could not get the links to work.

The file `script.js` is as follows,

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    "use strict";

    //------- Notifications Dropdowns
    $('.top-area > .setting-area > li').on("click", function() {
        $(this).siblings().children('div').removeClass('active');
        $(this).children('div').addClass('active');
        return false;
    });
    //------- remove class active on body
    $("body *").not('.top-area > .setting-area > li').on("click", function() {
        $(".top-area > .setting-area > li > div").removeClass('active');
    });


    //--- user setting dropdown on topbar   
    $('.user-img').on('click', function() {
        $('.user-setting').toggleClass("active");
        return false;
    });

    //--- side message box  
    $('.friendz-list > li, .chat-users > li').on('click', function() {
        $('.chat-box').addClass("show");
        return false;
    });
    $('.close-mesage').on('click', function() {
        $('.chat-box').removeClass("show");
        return false;
    });

    //------ scrollbar plugin
    if ($.isFunction($.fn.perfectScrollbar)) {
        $('.dropdowns, .twiter-feed, .invition, .followers, .chatting-area, .peoples, #people-list, .chat-list > ul, .message-list, .chat-users, .left-menu').perfectScrollbar();
    }

    /*--- socials menu scritp ---*/
    $('.trigger').on("click", function() {
        $(this).parent(".menu").toggleClass("active");
    });

    /*--- emojies show on text area ---*/
    $('.add-smiles > span').on("click", function() {
        $(this).parent().siblings(".smiles-bunch").toggleClass("active");
    });

    // delete notifications
    $('.notification-box > ul li > i.del').on("click", function() {
        $(this).parent().slideUp();
        return false;
    });

    /*--- socials menu scritp ---*/
    $('.f-page > figure i').on("click", function() {
        $(".drop").toggleClass("active");
    });

    //===== Search Filter =====//
    (function($) {
        // custom css expression for a case-insensitive contains()
        jQuery.expr[':'].Contains = function(a, i, m) {
            return (a.textContent || a.innerText || "").toUpperCase().indexOf(m[3].toUpperCase()) >= 0;
        };

        function listFilter(searchDir, list) {
            var form = $("<form>").attr({ "class": "filterform", "action": "#" }),
                input = $("<input>").attr({ "class": "filterinput", "type": "text", "placeholder": "Search Contacts..." });
            $(form).append(input).appendTo(searchDir);

            $(input)
                .change(function() {
                    var filter = $(this).val();
                    if (filter) {
                        $(list).find("li:not(:Contains(" + filter + "))").slideUp();
                        $(list).find("li:Contains(" + filter + ")").slideDown();
                    } else {
                        $(list).find("li").slideDown();
                    }
                    return false;
                })
                .keyup(function() {
                    $(this).change();
                });
        }

        //search friends widget
        $(function() {
            listFilter($("#searchDir"), $("#people-list"));
        });
    }(jQuery));

    //progress line for page loader
    $('body').show();
    NProgress.start();
    setTimeout(function() {
        NProgress.done();
        $('.fade').removeClass('out');
    }, 2000);

    //--- bootstrap tooltip 
    $(function() {
        $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
    });

    // Sticky Sidebar & header
    if ($(window).width() < 769) {
        jQuery(".sidebar").children().removeClass("stick-widget");
    }

    if ($.isFunction($.fn.stick_in_parent)) {
        $('.stick-widget').stick_in_parent({
            parent: '#page-contents',
            offset_top: 60,
        });


        $('.stick').stick_in_parent({
            parent: 'body',
            offset_top: 0,
        });

    }

    /*--- topbar setting dropdown ---*/
    $(".we-page-setting").on("click", function() {
        $(".wesetting-dropdown").toggleClass("active");
    });

    /*--- topbar toogle setting dropdown ---*/
    $('#nightmode').on('change', function() {
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            // Show popup window
            $(".theme-layout").addClass('black');
        } else {
            $(".theme-layout").removeClass("black");
        }
    });

    //chosen select plugin
    if ($.isFunction($.fn.chosen)) {
        $("select").chosen();
    }

    //----- add item plus minus button
    if ($.isFunction($.fn.userincr)) {
        $(".manual-adjust").userincr({
            buttonlabels: { 'dec': '-', 'inc': '+' },
        }).data({ 'min': 0, 'max': 20, 'step': 1 });
    }

    if ($.isFunction($.fn.loadMoreResults)) {
        $('.loadMore').loadMoreResults({
            displayedItems: 3,
            showItems: 1,
            button: {
                'class': 'btn-load-more',
                'text': 'Load More'
            }
        });
    }
    //===== owl carousel  =====//
    if ($.isFunction($.fn.owlCarousel)) {
        $('.sponsor-logo').owlCarousel({
            items: 6,
            loop: true,
            margin: 30,
            autoplay: true,
            autoplayTimeout: 1500,
            smartSpeed: 1000,
            autoplayHoverPause: true,
            nav: false,
            dots: false,
            responsiveClass: true,
            responsive: {
                0: {
                    items: 3,
                },
                600: {
                    items: 3,

                },
                1000: {
                    items: 6,
                }
            }

        });
    }

    // slick carousel for detail page
    if ($.isFunction($.fn.slick)) {
        $('.slider-for-gold').slick({
            slidesToShow: 1,
            slidesToScroll: 1,
            arrows: false,
            slide: 'li',
            fade: false,
            asNavFor: '.slider-nav-gold'
        });

        $('.slider-nav-gold').slick({
            slidesToShow: 3,
            slidesToScroll: 1,
            asNavFor: '.slider-for-gold',
            dots: false,
            arrows: true,
            slide: 'li',
            vertical: true,
            centerMode: true,
            centerPadding: '0',
            focusOnSelect: true,
            responsive: [{
                    breakpoint: 768,
                    settings: {
                        slidesToShow: 3,
                        slidesToScroll: 1,
                        infinite: true,
                        vertical: false,
                        centerMode: true,
                        dots: false,
                        arrows: false
                    }
                },
                {
                    breakpoint: 641,
                    settings: {
                        slidesToShow: 3,
                        slidesToScroll: 1,
                        infinite: true,
                        vertical: true,
                        centerMode: true,
                        dots: false,
                        arrows: false
                    }
                },
                {
                    breakpoint: 420,
                    settings: {
                        slidesToShow: 3,
                        slidesToScroll: 1,
                        infinite: true,
                        vertical: false,
                        centerMode: true,
                        dots: false,
                        arrows: false
                    }
                }
            ]
        });
    }

    //---- responsive header

    $(function() {

        //  create the menus
        $('#menu').mmenu();
        $('#shoppingbag').mmenu({
            navbar: {
                title: 'General Setting'
            },
            offCanvas: {
                position: 'right'
            }
        });

        //  fire the plugin
        $('.mh-head.first').mhead({
            scroll: {
                hide: 200
            }

        });
        $('.mh-head.second').mhead({
            scroll: false
        });


    });

    //**** Slide Panel Toggle ***//
    $("span.main-menu").on("click", function() {
        $(".side-panel").addClass('active');
        $(".theme-layout").addClass('active');
        return false;
    });

    $('.theme-layout').on("click", function() {
        $(this).removeClass('active');
        $(".side-panel").removeClass('active');


    });


    // login & register form
    $('button.signup').on("click", function() {
        $('.login-reg-bg').addClass('show');
        return false;
    });

    $('.already-have').on("click", function() {
        $('.login-reg-bg').removeClass('show');
        return false;
    });

    //----- count down timer        
    if ($.isFunction($.fn.downCount)) {
        $('.countdown').downCount({
            date: '11/12/2018 12:00:00',
            offset: +10
        });
    }

    /** Post a Comment **/
    // jQuery(".post-comt-box textarea").on("keydown", function(event) {

    //     if (event.keyCode == 13) {
    //         var comment = jQuery(this).val();
    //         var parent = jQuery(".showmore").parent("li");
    //         var comment_HTML = ' <li><div class="comet-avatar"><img src="images/resources/comet-1.jpg" alt=""></div><div class="we-comment"><div class="coment-head"><h5><a href="time-line.html" title="">Jason borne</a></h5><span>1 year ago</span><a class="we-reply" href="#" title="Reply"><i class="fa fa-reply"></i></a></div><p>' + comment + '</p></div></li>';
    //         $(comment_HTML).insertBefore(parent);
    //         jQuery(this).val('');
    //     }
    // });

    //inbox page    
    //***** Message Star *****//  
    $('.message-list > li > span.star-this').on("click", function() {
        $(this).toggleClass('starred');
    });


    //***** Message Important *****//
    $('.message-list > li > span.make-important').on("click", function() {
        $(this).toggleClass('important-done');
    });



    // Listen for click on toggle checkbox
    $('#select_all').on("click", function(event) {
        if (this.checked) {
            // Iterate each checkbox
            $('input:checkbox.select-message').each(function() {
                this.checked = true;
            });
        } else {
            $('input:checkbox.select-message').each(function() {
                this.checked = false;
            });
        }
    });


    $(".delete-email").on("click", function() {
        $(".message-list .select-message").each(function() {
            if (this.checked) {
                $(this).parent().slideUp();
            }
        });
    });

    // change background color on hover
    $('.category-box').hover(function() {
        $(this).addClass('selected');
        $(this).parent().siblings().children('.category-box').removeClass('selected');
    });


    //------- offcanvas menu 

    const menu = document.querySelector('#toggle');
    const menuItems = document.querySelector('#overlay');
    const menuContainer = document.querySelector('.menu-container');
    const menuIcon = document.querySelector('.canvas-menu i');

    function toggleMenu(e) {
        menuItems.classList.toggle('open');
        menuContainer.classList.toggle('full-menu');
        menuIcon.classList.toggle('fa-bars');
        menuIcon.classList.add('fa-times');
        e.preventDefault();
    }

    if (menu) {
        menu.addEventListener('click', toggleMenu, false);
    }

    // Responsive nav dropdowns
    $('.offcanvas-menu li.menu-item-has-children > a').on('click', function() {
        $(this).parent().siblings().children('ul').slideUp();
        $(this).parent().siblings().removeClass('active');
        $(this).parent().children('ul').slideToggle();
        $(this).parent().toggleClass('active');
        return false;
    });



}); //document ready end
```

Can anyone help me in finding out the problem?

Comment: So the problem is that, when you left click on a link, it doesn't do anything? Like, it doesn't open a new page or redirect you to another URL?

Comment: @crimsonpython24 Yes, exactly! It doesn't do anything if I **Left click** on it. 
(and weirdly enough, the link does work if I right click on it and open it in new tab)