# how to redirect to Hyperlink present in div

Tags: jquery, url, redirect

How do I make an entire `div` as hyperlink with the same URL as `<a>` inside this `div`? My jQuery is probably wrong.

```
<div>
   <a href="some-url"></a>
</div>

var $href = $('div > a').attr('href');
$('div').on('click', function(event) {
        $(this).location.href=$href;
})
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/796087/make-a-div-into-a-link

Comment: The body of your question has nothing to do with your title, which is already totally useless...

Comment: you are right @Bartdude i have edited the title :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try invoke the child anchor's click while user clicking on the `div`,

```
$('div').on('click', function(event) { 
    $(this).children('a')[0].click(); 
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/laraprabhu/BuLWs/)

Note: we did not use `$(this).children('a').click()` because this wont invoke the natural click of that anchor tag.

Comment: @Rajaprabhu Aravindasamy Sorry for the previous question. Actually i got the answer by accident. At that time i didnt know the reason why $(this).click() dont work. From the comments only i got the reason. :)

Comment: @AnoopJoshi Yeah.. i am just implementing what i learnt over there.. :)

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy Yeah, I know ;). +1 for your special "Note" :)

Comment: @user3686925 Glad to help..! and by the way, if you think that anyone of the answers here has satisfied your need then try to accept it by clicking on the tick mark present inside it.. And it is not a compulsion.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Use `window.location` to redirect the page

```
$('div').on('click', function(event) {

       $href =  $(this).find("a").attr('href');

        window.location.href= $href;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use jquery:

```
$('div').click(function(event) {
       var href =  $(this).find("a").attr('href');
        window.location.href=href;
});
```

add css for pointer:

```
div{cursor:pointer}
```

[<kbd>UPDATED DEMO</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/bLR37/2/)