# Display block a link into a div

Tags: html, css

I've this code

```css
.parent {
    width:100px;
    height:100%;
    background: green;
}

.parent a {
    display:block;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <h3>test</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Hic asperiores expedita rerum quos ullam qui saepe. Quas quasi dolorum quibusdam deserunt voluptas dolorem tenetur! Quam explicabo laboriosam quaerat iure ipsum.</p>
    <a href="#"></a>
</div>
```

I want my link to display fully into its container (which is `.parent`)

Have the div clickable with this link.

Comment: I suggest you to put `.parent` into `<a>` element - so it will change hole `div` into clickable link

Comment: possible duplicate of [Make a div into a link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/796087/make-a-div-into-a-link)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
.parent {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100%;
  background: green;
  position: relative;
}

.parent a {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

It should do the trick quite nicely if you don't want to wrap your div in an anchor tag.  Here's an [example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZGavqO).

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure I understand, but is this what you want?

```css
.parent {
  width:100px;
  height:100%;
  background: green;
}

.parent a {
  display:block;
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  width:inherit;
  height:inherit;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <h3>test</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Hic asperiores expedita rerum quos ullam qui saepe. Quas quasi dolorum quibusdam deserunt voluptas dolorem tenetur! Quam explicabo laboriosam quaerat iure ipsum.</p>
    <a href="#"></a>
</div>
```

Comment: Exactly ! Srry for my english, I'm french

Comment: That's fine :) Please accept my answer when you get the chance to :)

Answer (score -1):

have to  write a div inside the a tag.

```
    <a href="#"><div class="parent"> <h3>test</h3> <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit   amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Hic asperiores expedita rerum quos ullam qui saepe. Quas quasi dolorum quibusdam deserunt voluptas dolorem tenetur! Quam explicabo laboriosam quaerat iure ipsum.</p> <a href="#"></a> </div> </a>
```

Comment: slight correction - you can't have nested anchor elements - but prefectly valid. Obviously the person who downvoted this doesn't know correct HTML syntax.