# I want an event on my entire div clickable i.e my page should be redirected on click of a div

Tags: html

My Code:

```
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 indexpointer">
    <div class="img-txt-box3">
        <h2 class="box-text3">
            <a href="@Url.Action("Compare","Home")">
            Just<br>

            Compare
            </a>
        </h2>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.indexpointer {
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

My Question is: When I click on link pages I can open that following link, but as I have kept my div clickable, I want pages to be opened on click of div. So how can I achieve this?

Comment: Fiddle would be nice, hard to tell what you want to achieve.

Comment: Hope this helps you 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/796087/make-a-div-into-a-link

Comment: Ok i Have a div in which u can say in center der is a link  < a href="Something"> if i click on this link i can go to that following page ...but  i have kept now entire div clickable and i want if my users clicks on div then the above href should be triggered how to achieve this

Comment: You add a "handler" by using javascript. That acts on the click event raised when the div is clicked. inside the handler (a function) you can do whatever you like. For example redirect to another page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
$(".indexpointer").click(function(){
      window.location= $(this).find("a").attr("href");
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
<div onclick="location.href='url'">yadda yadda yadda</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$("div").click(function(){
    window.location=$(this).find("a").attr("href"); return false;
});
```

Make sure to use cursor:pointer for these DIVs

Answer (score 0):

Simple Solution:

```
<a href="http://yoursite.com">
  <div>
     Your content....
  </div>
</a>
```

**Using Jquery:**

```
$(".indexpointer").click(function() {
  window.location = $(this).find("a").attr("href"); 
  return false;
});
```

Comment: But this will change position