# Whole div a clickable link

Tags: php, html, css

I am trying to get my whole div a clickable link but I am not sure the correct way to do it. Would anyone be able to help me with this, it would be greatly appreciated. I am new to coding so I am still learning proper coding. Thanks.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  margin: auto;
  width: 1052px;
}

.container>div {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
  flex: 1;
  /*grow*/
  height: 210px;
  margin: 45px 10px 0px 10px;
  width: 231px;
}

.container img {
  height: 140px;
  width: 241px;
}

.container>div a {
  color: #353748;
  display: block;
  font-family: Netflix Sans, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 20px;
  padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  text-transform: initial;
}

.container>div a:hover {
  color: #353748;
  display: block;
  font-family: Netflix Sans, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 20px;
  padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
  text-decoration: underline;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  text-transform: initial;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>
    <img src="https://capebretonstartpage.com/1/wire-31023566-1595346165-638_636x382.jpg">
    <a href="https://www.capebretonstartpage.com/pages/about/" target="_blank">About vAdd An Image Add An Image</a>
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="https://capebretonstartpage.com/1/wire-31023566-1595346165-638_636x382.jpg">
    <a href="https://www.capebretonstartpage.com/pages/about/" target="_blank">About vAdd An Image Add An Image</a>
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="https://capebretonstartpage.com/1/wire-31023566-1595346165-638_636x382.jpg">
    <a href="https://www.capebretonstartpage.com/pages/about/" target="_blank">About vAdd An Image Add An Image</a>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Why do you have the same code repeated over and over?

Comment: I thought I needed to to have multiple rows.

Comment: Perhaps but not with repeated PHP

Comment: All that you need to do is `enclose the div in an anchor tag`.

Comment: Anyway next time first [Search your title](https://www.google.com/search?q=make+div+link+site%3Astackoverflow.com&oq=make+div+link+site%3Astackoverflow.com)

Comment: How else can I do it. Thanks

Comment: @JessieWilliams See the dupe. There were [MANY](https://www.google.com/search?q=make+div+link+site%3Astackoverflow.com&oq=make+div+link+site%3Astackoverflow.com)

Comment: How can I enclose the div in an anchor tag. thanks

Comment: [Scroll down the dupe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/796087/make-a-div-into-a-link), please. Just wrap the div in an A or look at the CSS solutions

Comment: Just change `<div><img src="https://capebretonstartpage.com/1/wire-31023566-1595346165-638_636x382.jpg"><a href="https://www.capebretonstartpage.com/pages/about/" target="_blank">About vAdd An Image Add An Image</a></div>` to this `<a href="https://www.capebretonstartpage.com/pages/about/" target="_blank"><div><img src="https://capebretonstartpage.com/1/wire-31023566-1595346165-638_636x382.jpg"><br/>About vAdd An Image Add An Image</div></a>` or drop the div completely and instead add `.container a { display:block}` to your CSS

Comment: That completely messes the whole div. It loses the border and the layout changes

Comment: That is because you need to now style the A instead of the DIV so you need to change the CSS accordingly

Answer (score -1):

You can put the `div` inside an `<a>` tag

Comment: Likely reason for downvote is that OP cannot delete this HUGE DUPE when there are answers. The question has been completely covered by the dupe that has 27 answers in it before you answered it

Comment: Can you possibly show me the code of the div in the <a> tag please.

Comment: Check your comments above someone have already done it

Comment: Already posted example in the comments to the question